# Installing OfBiz on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, debian, ofbiz

I attempted to setup OFBiz on PostgreSQL, but when I run the server, I get this error when I visit `http://server_address:8080/ecommerce/`:

```
org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ScreenRenderException: Error rendering screen [component://ecommerce/widget/CommonScreens.xml#main]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error running script at location [component://order/webapp/ordermgr/WEB-INF/actions/entry/catalog/Category.groovy]: org.ofbiz.entity.GenericEntityException: org.ofbiz.entity.transaction.GenericTransactionException: The current transaction is marked for rollback, not beginning a new transaction and aborting current operation; the rollbackOnly was caused by: Failure in findByCondition operation for entity [ProdCatalogCategory]: org.ofbiz.entity.GenericEntityException: org.postgresql.Driver (org.postgresql.Driver). Rolling back transaction.org.ofbiz.entity.GenericEntityException: org.postgresql.Driver (org.postgresql.Driver) (org.postgresql.Driver (org.postgresql.Driver)) (The current transaction is marked for rollback, not beginning a new transaction and aborting current operation; the rollbackOnly was caused by: Failure in findByCondition operation for entity [ProdCatalogCategory]: org.ofbiz.entity.GenericEntityException: org.postgresql.Driver (org.postgresql.Driver). Rolling back transaction.org.ofbiz.entity.GenericEntityException: org.postgresql.Driver (org.postgresql.Driver) (org.postgresql.Driver (org.postgresql.Driver))) (Error running script at location [component://order/webapp/ordermgr/WEB-INF/actions/entry/catalog/Category.groovy]: org.ofbiz.entity.GenericEntityException: org.ofbiz.entity.transaction.GenericTransactionException: The current transaction is marked for rollback, not beginning a new transaction and aborting current operation; the rollbackOnly was caused by: Failure in findByCondition operation for entity [ProdCatalogCategory]: org.ofbiz.entity.GenericEntityException: org.postgresql.Driver (org.postgresql.Driver). Rolling back transaction.org.ofbiz.entity.GenericEntityException: org.postgresql.Driver (org.postgresql.Driver) (org.postgresql.Driver (org.postgresql.Driver)) (The current transaction is marked for rollback, not beginning a new transaction and aborting current operation; the rollbackOnly was caused by: Failure in findByCondition operation for entity [ProdCatalogCategory]: org.ofbiz.entity.GenericEntityException: org.postgresql.Driver (org.postgresql.Driver). Rolling back transaction.org.ofbiz.entity.GenericEntityException: org.postgresql.Driver (org.postgresql.Driver) (org.postgresql.Driver (org.postgresql.Driver))))
```

However, I have no idea what it means. I setup a basic database called `ofbiz` with the owner as the `ofbiz` user. Then ran `./ant load-demo` to populate the database with the demo data. My operating system is Debian GNU/Linux 7.2. I should also note that I'm a newcomer to PostgreSQL, OFBiz, and Java. I'm sorry about formatting, this is how it came.

Comment: Show your exception(if exists) when you start OFBiz, think you miss Postgres jar file or you have wrong entotyconfig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. I am assuming that PostgreSQL driver are missing. By default ofbiz doesnt come with PostgreSQL drivers so you need to download it. Go to ofbiz directory and run the following command 
ant download-PG-JDBC in windows or ./ant download-PG-JDBC for linux .